# What restrictions does merged mining place on the sidechain?

Tags: blockchain, merged-mining, sidechains

What restrictions are imposed by merged mining on the structure or functionality of a side chain (besides it having to use the same PoW schema)?  For example, could the side chain have a higher block rate than the parent chain?